Update in Apexcharts the tickamount dynamically based on screen width
I'm testing for the first time some libraries to create graphs in JavaScript of Open Source type to understand which one is the most interesting and suitable for me.

I was trying to update tickamount in Apexcharts on xaxis with type: 'category' (with a simple JavaScript function code).
In the labels there are timestamps formatted as string.
I can't use the type: 'datetime' because some points in dates are null (there's not the example case, full filled).
So watch this snippet.
If I resize my browser window the tickAmount it's replaced with tickAmount: newtickamount correctly, but I got completely different values on the xaxis.
Open the full-size snippet to see the result on xaxis change (by clicking on the top right of the snippet).
It's a bug or I'm doing something wrong?


    var options = {
        chart: {
            width: '100%',
            height: '400px',
            stacked: false,
            toolbar: { show: false, },
        },
        labels: [
        "29 08 2024 07:04:31", "29 08 2024 07:04:41", "29 08 2024 07:04:51", "29 08 2024 07:05:01", "29 08 2024 07:05:11", "29 08 2024 07:05:21", "29 08 2024 07:05:31", "29 08 2024 07:05:41", "29 08 2024 07:05:51", "29 08 2024 07:06:01", "29 08 2024 07:06:11", "29 08 2024 07:06:21", "29 08 2024 07:06:31", "29 08 2024 07:06:41", "29 08 2024 07:06:51", "29 08 2024 07:07:01", "29 08 2024 07:07:11", "29 08 2024 07:07:21", "29 08 2024 07:07:31", "29 08 2024 07:07:41", "29 08 2024 07:07:51", "29 08 2024 07:08:01", "29 08 2024 07:08:11", "29 08 2024 07:08:21", "29 08 2024 07:08:31", "29 08 2024 07:08:41", "29 08 2024 07:08:51", "29 08 2024 07:09:01", "29 08 2024 07:09:11", "29 08 2024 07:09:21", "29 08 2024 07:09:31", "29 08 2024 07:09:41", "29 08 2024 07:09:51", "29 08 2024 07:10:01", "29 08 2024 07:10:11", "29 08 2024 07:10:21", "29 08 2024 07:10:31", "29 08 2024 07:10:41", "29 08 2024 07:10:51", "29 08 2024 07:11:01", "29 08 2024 07:11:11", "29 08 2024 07:11:21", "29 08 2024 07:11:31", "29 08 2024 07:11:41", "29 08 2024 07:11:51", "29 08 2024 07:12:01", "29 08 2024 07:12:11", "29 08 2024 07:12:21", "29 08 2024 07:12:31", "29 08 2024 07:12:41", "29 08 2024 07:12:51", "29 08 2024 07:13:01", "29 08 2024 07:13:11", "29 08 2024 07:13:21", "29 08 2024 07:13:31", "29 08 2024 07:13:41", "29 08 2024 07:13:51", "29 08 2024 07:14:01", "29 08 2024 07:14:11", "29 08 2024 07:14:21", "29 08 2024 07:14:31", "29 08 2024 07:14:41", "29 08 2024 07:14:51", "29 08 2024 07:15:01", "29 08 2024 07:15:11", "29 08 2024 07:15:21", "29 08 2024 07:15:31", "29 08 2024 07:15:41", "29 08 2024 07:15:51", "29 08 2024 07:16:01", "29 08 2024 07:16:11", "29 08 2024 07:16:21", "29 08 2024 07:16:31", "29 08 2024 07:16:41", "29 08 2024 07:16:51", "29 08 2024 07:17:01", "29 08 2024 07:17:11", "29 08 2024 07:17:21", "29 08 2024 07:17:31", "29 08 2024 07:17:41", "29 08 2024 07:17:51", "29 08 2024 07:18:01", "29 08 2024 07:18:11", "29 08 2024 07:18:21", "29 08 2024 07:18:31", "29 08 2024 07:18:41", "29 08 2024 07:18:51", "29 08 2024 07:19:01", "29 08 2024 07:19:11", "29 08 2024 07:19:21", "29 08 2024 07:19:31", "29 08 2024 07:19:41", "29 08 2024 07:19:51", "29 08 2024 07:20:01", "29 08 2024 07:20:11", "29 08 2024 07:20:21", "29 08 2024 07:20:31", "29 08 2024 07:20:41", "29 08 2024 07:20:51",
    ],

        series: [{
            name: 'Hello',
            info: 'hello',
            type: 'line',
            data: [
                357, 171, 472, 909, 707, 411, 470, 990, 112, 369, 428, 451, 44, 869, 710, 782, 718, 491, 479, 976, 438, 953, 976, 363, 886, 479, 274, 809, 625, 808, 569, 226, 158, 646, 196, 506, 754, 114, 513, 535, 271, 428, 155, 97, 412, 661, 181, 118, 616, 297, 23, 460, 344, 274, 467, 937, 839, 355, 290, 765, 647, 462, 90, 439, 737, 439, 194, 186, 973, 667, 181, 425, 84, 453, 43, 835, 99, 209, 580, 465, 329, 740, 541, 237, 17, 631, 916, 300, 745, 826, 63, 900, 990, 450, 560, 99, 21, 981, 954,
            ],

            },
        ],

        stroke: {
            width: 2,
            curve: 'smooth',
        },
        
        xaxis: {
            type: 'category',     //category    datetime     numeric
            //tickAmount: 20,
            tooltip: { enabled: false, },
            tickPlacement: 'on',
            labels: { rotate: -60, },
        },
        
        
        yaxis: [
          {
            show: true,
            labels: {
                show: true,
            },
            axisBorder: { show: false, },
            axisTicks: { show: false, },
            tooltip: { enabled: true, offsetX: -20, },
          },
        ],
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            shared: true,
            intersect: false,
            inverseOrder: false,
            //custom: function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {   return 'HELLO!';  }),
        }       
    };

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
    chart.render();
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
  
    //Replacing tickamount
    function replace_tickamount(){
        width = document.body.clientWidth;
        newtickamount = 0;
        
        if (width > 1000){
            newtickamount = 10;
        } else if (width > 500) {
            newtickamount = 8;
        } else {
            newtickamount = 4;
        }
        
        chart.updateOptions({
            xaxis: { type: 'category', tickAmount: newtickamount, },
        });

    }



    addEventListener("resize", (event) => { 
      replace_tickamount();
    });

    
<div id="chart"></div>
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
body { font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; }
#chart { max-width: 100%; border: 1px solid #000; }
</style>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>




EDIT AFTER THE ANSWER OF @kikon
Seems the "bug" it's bigger than I expected.
If you use the first solution you propose and you change the tickAmount manually, like
    newtickamount = 0;
    if (width > 1000){ newtickamount = 7; }
    chart.updateOptions({
        xaxis: { type: 'category', tickAmount: newtickamount, categories: options.labels, },
    });

you got some values of tickAmount differents.
Try to change and see.
For newtickamount = 5 the graph prints 6 ticks.
For newtickamount = 7 the graph prints 9 ticks.
For newtickamount = 10 the graph prints 11 ticks.
There's something wrong with the inner calculation (that also I didn't even ask for).
Graphically I would like to get a first and last value to make the result more beautiful visually (using a small function that uses chart.w.globals.categoryLabels.length).
But in these conditions it seems useless to change the tickamount.

Please note that the issue in the update is unrelated to the original problem with labels transformed to numbers. tickAmount is not precise and that is a bug in AxesUtils#checkLabelBasedOnTickamount but that's always so, it is not related to any change. You can verify that by setting tickAmount in the initial configuration you'll see that without any resizing or axis updates, the number of tick labels will not usually be equal to the value of tickAmount.

That problem has been already been discovered, see this post. An alternative solution can be imagined, if you want to set an exact number of tick labels, possibly with the first and last ticks on, but again, that is another problem altogether.

@kikon Yes, it's what I'm searching for. Ticks calculation from an external writed function to have a first and a last value. Sorry, but this time I'm not agree. The post u linked gives a solution for labels in numeric category. So ticks are calculated on numbers. And also don't talks about the problem of wrong ticks number when I set it manually. I think that apexchart has it still a lot to optimize its library. My thoughts are that is optimized for number and they have to works also on text input on label. Tnx the same

The post I linked to didn't have a solution because it didn't have the full code, as you provided here. My suggestion was that you  ask another question, about "an exact number of ticklabels with the first and last one selected", based more or less on the same code from this one. As you know, each post should have only one issue, so that would make sense.

@kikon ok. The thumb up it's yours again. Your solution it's correct and the code you write also. It does what it's supposed to do. The post u linked it's completely different from the request. So u're ok. But the ticks of the graph must behave as expected from the setting. It's full of correction to do to increase his value. Thanks. Good coding

You may say it's a bug; or a dubious sort of feature ...
Apexcharts performs in certain conditions (horizontal bar + unsupported zoom + tick placement !== 'between', etc.)
a conversion of x axis from category to numeric, see the source code.
You can check that by adding a console.log(chart.w.config.xaxis.type) after chart.render() - you'll get numeric, not
category, which you set. I suppose the reason for that is some intended optimization.
To still preserve the original categories, it also creates an xaxis.labels.formatter option, that maps the new numbers to
those original labels. However, when you updateOptions for the xaxis, that formatter is lost.
The simplest solution seems to me to just set the categories option of the axis when you updateOptions:
chart.updateOptions({
    xaxis: { type: 'category', tickAmount: newtickamount, categories: options.labels}
})

the original snippet with this change:


var options = {
    chart: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '400px',
        stacked: false,
        toolbar: { show: false, },
    },
    labels: [
        "29 08 2024 07:04:31", "29 08 2024 07:04:41", "29 08 2024 07:04:51", "29 08 2024 07:05:01", "29 08 2024 07:05:11", "29 08 2024 07:05:21", "29 08 2024 07:05:31", "29 08 2024 07:05:41", "29 08 2024 07:05:51", "29 08 2024 07:06:01", "29 08 2024 07:06:11", "29 08 2024 07:06:21", "29 08 2024 07:06:31", "29 08 2024 07:06:41", "29 08 2024 07:06:51", "29 08 2024 07:07:01", "29 08 2024 07:07:11", "29 08 2024 07:07:21", "29 08 2024 07:07:31", "29 08 2024 07:07:41", "29 08 2024 07:07:51", "29 08 2024 07:08:01", "29 08 2024 07:08:11", "29 08 2024 07:08:21", "29 08 2024 07:08:31", "29 08 2024 07:08:41", "29 08 2024 07:08:51", "29 08 2024 07:09:01", "29 08 2024 07:09:11", "29 08 2024 07:09:21", "29 08 2024 07:09:31", "29 08 2024 07:09:41", "29 08 2024 07:09:51", "29 08 2024 07:10:01", "29 08 2024 07:10:11", "29 08 2024 07:10:21", "29 08 2024 07:10:31", "29 08 2024 07:10:41", "29 08 2024 07:10:51", "29 08 2024 07:11:01", "29 08 2024 07:11:11", "29 08 2024 07:11:21", "29 08 2024 07:11:31", "29 08 2024 07:11:41", "29 08 2024 07:11:51", "29 08 2024 07:12:01", "29 08 2024 07:12:11", "29 08 2024 07:12:21", "29 08 2024 07:12:31", "29 08 2024 07:12:41", "29 08 2024 07:12:51", "29 08 2024 07:13:01", "29 08 2024 07:13:11", "29 08 2024 07:13:21", "29 08 2024 07:13:31", "29 08 2024 07:13:41", "29 08 2024 07:13:51", "29 08 2024 07:14:01", "29 08 2024 07:14:11", "29 08 2024 07:14:21", "29 08 2024 07:14:31", "29 08 2024 07:14:41", "29 08 2024 07:14:51", "29 08 2024 07:15:01", "29 08 2024 07:15:11", "29 08 2024 07:15:21", "29 08 2024 07:15:31", "29 08 2024 07:15:41", "29 08 2024 07:15:51", "29 08 2024 07:16:01", "29 08 2024 07:16:11", "29 08 2024 07:16:21", "29 08 2024 07:16:31", "29 08 2024 07:16:41", "29 08 2024 07:16:51", "29 08 2024 07:17:01", "29 08 2024 07:17:11", "29 08 2024 07:17:21", "29 08 2024 07:17:31", "29 08 2024 07:17:41", "29 08 2024 07:17:51", "29 08 2024 07:18:01", "29 08 2024 07:18:11", "29 08 2024 07:18:21", "29 08 2024 07:18:31", "29 08 2024 07:18:41", "29 08 2024 07:18:51", "29 08 2024 07:19:01", "29 08 2024 07:19:11", "29 08 2024 07:19:21", "29 08 2024 07:19:31", "29 08 2024 07:19:41", "29 08 2024 07:19:51", "29 08 2024 07:20:01", "29 08 2024 07:20:11", "29 08 2024 07:20:21", "29 08 2024 07:20:31", "29 08 2024 07:20:41", "29 08 2024 07:20:51",
    ],

    series: [{
        name: 'Hello',
        info: 'hello',
        type: 'line',
        data: [
            357, 171, 472, 909, 707, 411, 470, 990, 112, 369, 428, 451, 44, 869, 710, 782, 718, 491, 479, 976, 438, 953, 976, 363, 886, 479, 274, 809, 625, 808, 569, 226, 158, 646, 196, 506, 754, 114, 513, 535, 271, 428, 155, 97, 412, 661, 181, 118, 616, 297, 23, 460, 344, 274, 467, 937, 839, 355, 290, 765, 647, 462, 90, 439, 737, 439, 194, 186, 973, 667, 181, 425, 84, 453, 43, 835, 99, 209, 580, 465, 329, 740, 541, 237, 17, 631, 916, 300, 745, 826, 63, 900, 990, 450, 560, 99, 21, 981, 954,
        ],
    }],

    stroke: {
        width: 2,
        curve: 'smooth',
    },

    xaxis: {
        type: 'category',     //category    datetime     numeric
        //tickAmount: 20,
        tooltip: { enabled: false, },
        tickPlacement: 'on',
        labels: { rotate: -60, },
    },


    yaxis: [
        {
            show: true,
            labels: {
                show: true,
            },
            axisBorder: { show: false, },
            axisTicks: { show: false, },
            tooltip: { enabled: true, offsetX: -20, },
        },
    ],
    tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        shared: true,
        intersect: false,
        inverseOrder: false,
        //custom: function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {   return 'HELLO!';  }),
    }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
console.log(chart.w.config.xaxis.type)

//Replacing tickamount
function replace_tickamount(){
    width = document.body.clientWidth;
    newtickamount = 0;

    if (width > 1000){
        newtickamount = 10;
    } else if (width > 500) {
        newtickamount = 8;
    } else {
        newtickamount = 4;
    }

    chart.updateOptions({
        xaxis: { type: 'category', tickAmount: newtickamount, categories: options.labels},
    });

}

addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
    replace_tickamount();
});
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>



Another possibility is to explicitly preserve the labels.formatter that was set by the system when it converted the axis:
chart.updateOptions({
    xaxis: { 
       tickAmount: newtickamount, 
       labels: {formatter: chart.w.config.xaxis.labels.formatter}
    }
})

the original snippet with this change:


var options = {
    chart: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '400px',
        stacked: false,
        toolbar: { show: false, },
    },
    labels: [
        "29 08 2024 07:04:31", "29 08 2024 07:04:41", "29 08 2024 07:04:51", "29 08 2024 07:05:01", "29 08 2024 07:05:11", "29 08 2024 07:05:21", "29 08 2024 07:05:31", "29 08 2024 07:05:41", "29 08 2024 07:05:51", "29 08 2024 07:06:01", "29 08 2024 07:06:11", "29 08 2024 07:06:21", "29 08 2024 07:06:31", "29 08 2024 07:06:41", "29 08 2024 07:06:51", "29 08 2024 07:07:01", "29 08 2024 07:07:11", "29 08 2024 07:07:21", "29 08 2024 07:07:31", "29 08 2024 07:07:41", "29 08 2024 07:07:51", "29 08 2024 07:08:01", "29 08 2024 07:08:11", "29 08 2024 07:08:21", "29 08 2024 07:08:31", "29 08 2024 07:08:41", "29 08 2024 07:08:51", "29 08 2024 07:09:01", "29 08 2024 07:09:11", "29 08 2024 07:09:21", "29 08 2024 07:09:31", "29 08 2024 07:09:41", "29 08 2024 07:09:51", "29 08 2024 07:10:01", "29 08 2024 07:10:11", "29 08 2024 07:10:21", "29 08 2024 07:10:31", "29 08 2024 07:10:41", "29 08 2024 07:10:51", "29 08 2024 07:11:01", "29 08 2024 07:11:11", "29 08 2024 07:11:21", "29 08 2024 07:11:31", "29 08 2024 07:11:41", "29 08 2024 07:11:51", "29 08 2024 07:12:01", "29 08 2024 07:12:11", "29 08 2024 07:12:21", "29 08 2024 07:12:31", "29 08 2024 07:12:41", "29 08 2024 07:12:51", "29 08 2024 07:13:01", "29 08 2024 07:13:11", "29 08 2024 07:13:21", "29 08 2024 07:13:31", "29 08 2024 07:13:41", "29 08 2024 07:13:51", "29 08 2024 07:14:01", "29 08 2024 07:14:11", "29 08 2024 07:14:21", "29 08 2024 07:14:31", "29 08 2024 07:14:41", "29 08 2024 07:14:51", "29 08 2024 07:15:01", "29 08 2024 07:15:11", "29 08 2024 07:15:21", "29 08 2024 07:15:31", "29 08 2024 07:15:41", "29 08 2024 07:15:51", "29 08 2024 07:16:01", "29 08 2024 07:16:11", "29 08 2024 07:16:21", "29 08 2024 07:16:31", "29 08 2024 07:16:41", "29 08 2024 07:16:51", "29 08 2024 07:17:01", "29 08 2024 07:17:11", "29 08 2024 07:17:21", "29 08 2024 07:17:31", "29 08 2024 07:17:41", "29 08 2024 07:17:51", "29 08 2024 07:18:01", "29 08 2024 07:18:11", "29 08 2024 07:18:21", "29 08 2024 07:18:31", "29 08 2024 07:18:41", "29 08 2024 07:18:51", "29 08 2024 07:19:01", "29 08 2024 07:19:11", "29 08 2024 07:19:21", "29 08 2024 07:19:31", "29 08 2024 07:19:41", "29 08 2024 07:19:51", "29 08 2024 07:20:01", "29 08 2024 07:20:11", "29 08 2024 07:20:21", "29 08 2024 07:20:31", "29 08 2024 07:20:41", "29 08 2024 07:20:51",
    ],

    series: [{
        name: 'Hello',
        info: 'hello',
        type: 'line',
        data: [
            357, 171, 472, 909, 707, 411, 470, 990, 112, 369, 428, 451, 44, 869, 710, 782, 718, 491, 479, 976, 438, 953, 976, 363, 886, 479, 274, 809, 625, 808, 569, 226, 158, 646, 196, 506, 754, 114, 513, 535, 271, 428, 155, 97, 412, 661, 181, 118, 616, 297, 23, 460, 344, 274, 467, 937, 839, 355, 290, 765, 647, 462, 90, 439, 737, 439, 194, 186, 973, 667, 181, 425, 84, 453, 43, 835, 99, 209, 580, 465, 329, 740, 541, 237, 17, 631, 916, 300, 745, 826, 63, 900, 990, 450, 560, 99, 21, 981, 954,
        ],
    }],

    stroke: {
        width: 2,
        curve: 'smooth',
    },

    xaxis: {
        type: 'category',     //category    datetime     numeric
        //tickAmount: 20,
        tooltip: { enabled: false, },
        tickPlacement: 'on',
        labels: { rotate: -60, },
    },


    yaxis: [
        {
            show: true,
            labels: {
                show: true,
            },
            axisBorder: { show: false, },
            axisTicks: { show: false, },
            tooltip: { enabled: true, offsetX: -20, },
        },
    ],
    tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        shared: true,
        intersect: false,
        inverseOrder: false,
        //custom: function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {   return 'HELLO!';  }),
    }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
console.log(chart.w.config.xaxis.type)

//Replacing tickamount
function replace_tickamount(){
    width = document.body.clientWidth;
    newtickamount = 0;

    if (width > 1000){
        newtickamount = 10;
    } else if (width > 500) {
        newtickamount = 8;
    } else {
        newtickamount = 4;
    }

    chart.updateOptions({
      xaxis: {  
         tickAmount: newtickamount,
         labels: {
            formatter: chart.w.config.xaxis.labels.formatter
         }
      },
    });

}

addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
    replace_tickamount();
});
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>




Kikon u the best one! I use this. Exactly the first. I think that categories: options.labels it's the fastest way because the formatter should make more assignment and more 'calculations'. Anyway I didn't say anywhere to change the labels, and also I don't have declared nothing in the source code about the type that becomes numeric (as u see from console). So for me it's a BIG BUG BAG️. Tnx for the answer! Thumb Up for u. U made my day better. All knowledge gained!

That is a nice and very well-descriptive answer.+1

wrap with a div and use css to achive this best way to do this dvw like width:100dvw

Yes, it's possible, but there are too much values on x axis. So by setting the tickAmountthe graph it's more clean. Tnx the same.
